# display products inline - special ID's required?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm doing front end development for a project between some friends.

He is building the backed in rails and has templates that will generate the products and put the content in but I'm running into a situation where I'm not sure how to make them align properly?

This is a web based platform.

Here is the situation with the products. I have three for example. I created a product container that will hold them. I have the first one showing perfectly, then when I copy pasted another two (just to see them) they don't generate.

```
<div class="main-bkg">
    <div class="card-row">
        <div class="product-cont">
            <div class="product-holder">
                <div class="product-img"> <img src="img/box.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="product-name">prod1</div>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <div class="product-price">$99</div>
                    <div class="sep">-</div>
                    <div class="product-desc">box</div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-qty">
                    <div class="qty-sub">-</div>
                    <div class="qty-amount">1</div>
                    <div class="qty-add">+</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-cont">
            <div class="product-holder">
                <div class="product-img"> <img src="img/circle.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="product-name">prod2</div>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <div class="product-price">$99</div>
                    <div class="sep">-</div>
                    <div class="product-desc">circle</div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-qty">
                    <div class="qty-sub">-</div>
                    <div class="qty-amount">1</div>
                    <div class="qty-add">+</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-cont">
            <div class="product-holder">
                <div class="product-img"> <img src="img/tri.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="product-name">prod3</div>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <div class="product-price">$99</div>
                    <div class="sep">-</div>
                    <div class="product-desc">triangle</div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-qty">
                    <div class="qty-sub">-</div>
                    <div class="qty-amount">1</div>
                    <div class="qty-add">+</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css is build in SASS, and I'll post in that for easy reading. If you want the css export I can show it.

I assume they are overlapping. I'm not totally sure an easy work around this other then giving each product a special ID and then applying styling to it.

```
.main-bkg {
    padding-top: 165px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #ebf0f1;
    .card-row {
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        .product-cont {
            padding-left: 30px;
            padding-right: 30px;
            .product-holder {
                background-color: white;
                height: 350px;
                width: 200px;
                border-radius: 20x;
                .product-img {
                    img {
                        display: block;
                        height: 240px;
                        width: 170px;
                        margin-left: auto;
                        margin-right: auto;
                        padding-top: 15px;
                    }
                }
                .product-name {
                    text-align: center;
                }
                .product-info {
                    display: block;
                    height: 30px;
                    width: 100px;
                    text-align: center;
                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto;
                    font-weight: 700;
                    .product-price {
                        display: inline-block;
                        text-align: center;
                        float: left;
                    }
                    .sep {
                        display: inline-block;
                        text-align: center;
                    }
                    .product-desc {
                        display: inline-block;
                        text-align: center;
                        float: right;
                    }
                }
                .product-qty {
                    display: block;
                    border-radius: 3px;
                    border: 1px solid $prime-color;
                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto;
                    width: 100px;
                    .qty-sub {
                        color: $prime-color;
                        display: inline-block;
                        float: left;
                        width: 30px;
                        height: 25px;
                        text-align: center;
                    }
                    .qty-amount {
                        display: inline-block;
                        color: $prime-color;
                        font-size: 20px;
                        text-align: center;
                        width: 40px;
                        height: 25px;
                    }
                    .qty-add {
                        color: $prime-color;
                        display: inline-block;
                        text-align: center;
                        float: right;
                        width: 30px;
                        height: 25px;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure your page is updated with your newest HTML? From what you posted, it doesn't look like there would be anything causing them to overlap.

Comment: Oh sorry yes, they align below each other. Thank you.

Comment: You want them to display next to each other?

Comment: Yes, I got that to work. I used float:left , would that have been the correct way?

Comment: Yes, using floats will work. If you wanted some more control, you could use more modern layout techniques such as flexbox (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or CSS grids.

Comment: That's great! Thank you, I've actually never seen that.

Comment: Aside, you're way past the [sass inception rule](http://thesassway.com/beginner/the-inception-rule) there and that specificity and DOM order dependency will probably come back to bite you. Since you have classes on everything there's really no need for all that nesting

Comment: Thank you, I never knew that either. I'll apply those changes right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to put a **float:left** in the container to let the container float?

```
.product-cont {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  float: left;
}
```

Check if this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/xjeeh/pen/mWqEGw) with SASS ready solves your problem